# Can I register one TcpListener on multiple mio Poll objects?

Tags: rust, mio

Can I register the same `TcpListener` on multiple mio `Poll` objects (one `Poll` per thread for a multi-threaded server)?

When I try, I get the error:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
>   value:  Error { repr: Custom(Custom { kind: Other, error:
>   StringError("socket  already registered") }) }',
>   src/libcore/result.rs:788

Is this intended behavior?